# PHP: Find total number of images having same name in a folder

Tags: php

I am creating code to upload images in a folder using PHP, & before upload an image I check that if any image with same name already exists in the folder by using below syntax:

```
if (file_exists('profilephoto/' . 'frame.gif')) {
}
```

But actually I don't want to restrict the user to upload more images with same name & obviously it is impossible to save **two images with same name** , but there is a way to just find total number of images with same name & upload the next image with appending ***total number + 1*** with image name.

Now I just want to know that using PHP how could we find total number of images having same name in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$i = '';
while ( file_exists($filename = ('profilephoto/' . "frame$i.gif")) )
  ++$i;

echo $filename;
?>
```

Obviously it's subject to "race conditions," but that's probably the least of your concerns.